# How to properly move XAML files to a folder?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I made a simple WPF program contain an UserControl, let's name it `CustomImage` where it contains several images.

And another UserControl using `CustomImage` as elements.

It all worked fine until I created some folders and moving things around for organizing purposes.

The UserControl using `CustomImage` starts to show errors saying something like the element can't find resources from something or somewhere. (Sorry, I'm using Chinese version, so I don't really know what it was said originally in English.)

But the funny thing is, I can see the images correctly inside `CustomImage` itself, but not the UserControls using it!

I can't find anything related to this in Google, as it was mostly talking about how to move files "through code" or something.

And I don't really even know where to start debugging it because the error is in XAML, not the code. And it didn't give me any auto-fix options for the same reason.

So, somebody PLEASE be so kind and teach me how to fix it.

Much appreciated!

PS. I found `System.Uri resourceLocater = new System.Uri("/WpfApp1;...` in the `InitiallizeComponent`, but it seems to be not changeable because every time I change it and recompile, it changed back!

Comment: If simple moving or cutting and pasting of files doesn't work, you could always create a new file with a new name and copy over the *contents* of the old file to it before you simply delete the old file. Apart from this, there is no "magic" solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try right clicking the Solution > Clean, and then Rebuild. Tends to work for me when a view "can't find" a referenced view in another folder even though it is clearly there.